# How to output "hello" value only once from array containing "hello" two times?

Tags: java, arrays, string, output

the main goal is to write a method that finds the longest string in any given array. I don't quite understand how to adjust my code so that "hello" string value is output only once from the above array.

Could someone please suggest how to correct the code? Thanks in advance!

````
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] massive = {"hello", "hello", "ola", "bye", "ciao"};
        String longestString = "";
        String maxString = "";
        for (String string : massive) {
            if (string.length() > longestString.length()) {
                longestString = string;
                maxString = string;
                continue;
            }
            if (string.length() == longestString.length()) {
                longestString = string;
                maxString += ", " + string;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxString);
    }
}```
````

Comment: What should be the output if there are two *different* words with the same maximum length? For example, if you added `"wazup"` to the array?

Comment: you could try `maxString += ", " + string;` --> `if (!maxString.contains(string)) { `maxString += ", " + string; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (string.length() == longestString.length()) {
           longestString = string;
           maxString += ", " + string;
       }
```

remove this part, it adds, the second one at the end of first.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (string.length() == longestString.length()) {
    longestString = string;
    maxString += ", " + string;
}
```

This part of the code appends any string that is found to be equal to the longest string found thus far.

In order to keep only the longest string that appears first, just remove this block.

If on the other hand you wish to keep the last, after removing, make the first if statement to check equality too:

```
if (string.length() >= longestString.length())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I solved this:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] massive = {"hello", "hello", "ola", "bye", "ciao"};
        int longestString = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < massive.length; i++) {
            if (massive[i].length() > massive[longestString].length) {
                longestString = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(massive[longestString]);
    }
}
```

Every iteration of the loop, I check to see if the current word is longer than the `longestString`, and at the end of the loop, it prints out the longest one.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should contain the data differently.
Create the appended string after the loop; checking if the value already exists.

```java
String[] massive = {"hello", "hello", "wazup", "ola", "bye", "ciao"};
String longestString = "";
String maxString = "";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (String string : massive) {
    if (string.length() > longestString.length()) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(longestString = string);
    } else if (string.length() == longestString.length()) {
        if (!list.contains(string)) list.add(string);
    }
}

maxString = String.join(", ", list);
System.out.println(maxString);
```

Output

```
hello, wazup
```

Comment: Hello! thank you for the answer. 

But what if in the case of {"hello", "wazup", "ola", "bye", "ciao"} array I have to get hello, wazup as output? 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the right solution as below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] massive = {"hello", "abcde", "ola", "bye", "ciao"};
        String longestString = "";
        String maxString = "";
        for (String string : massive) {
            if (string.length() > longestString.length()) {
                longestString = string;
                maxString = string;
                continue;
            }
            if (string.length() == longestString.length()) {
                longestString = string;
                if (!maxString.contains(string)) {
                    maxString += ", " + string;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxString);
    }
}
```

My mistake in forming the question was that I did not fully spell out the requirements of the task. Here are the requirements:

`["hello", "ola", "bye", "ciao"]` -> hello

`["hello", "hello", "ola", "bye", "ciao"]` -> hello

`["hello", "bingo", "ola", "bye", "ciao"]` -> hello, bingo